# Bitcoin Wallet generation and TX signing

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development

I am developing a Bitcoin Wallet in Javascript. I've worked on ETH but it's my first time on BTC. Here are following queries if anyone can help:

1. How do we generate bitcoin Wallet like we do in Ethereum. PrivateKey -> PubKey -> Address and Private Key is used to sign a rawTx, searlize and then broadcast. What I'll need to make this happen in Bitcoin.
2. I've gone through docs of some libraries [Bitcore](https://bitcore.io/), [Bcoin](https://bcoin.io/) and [cryptocoinjs](http://cryptocoinjs.com/) but all of them tell to connect to a node(test/live) to generate wallet etc.
3. Is there any way(lib) to generate a wallet, Load wallet from privatekey, sign TX from private keys all of this offline,and then propogating this to node. How this is done in Bitcoin.
4. What Bitcoin node can i use for mainnet?

Comment: There is a lot here, but I would have a look at https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib it has examples, and can do all you are looking to do. It requires a connection with a bitcoin node via RPC. Alternatively, Bitcore will run its own implementation of a full node.